# How to share C++ static variable between PHP requests in an PHP extension

Tags: php, c++, php-7, php-extension

I have written an PHP 7.X extension to my C++ program. 
My C++ program has an Excelsior JET JNI environment which is created as a static variable at the start of the program and released at the end.

The threads are created by the JET Runtime, e.g. GC thread, weak reference handler thread, finalizers thread, etc. I create the threads in the PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(extprog)

These threads should live for the duration of the execution of the php script and close at the end of the PHP request.

To make sure the clean up of the JET threads happens I have added a release method in the MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION of the PHP extension.

The problem is when I run the PHP extension in the browser it just hangs. If I remove the code to manage the JET threads the PHP scripts run, but does not kill the JET threads.

How can I manage these resources between requests? Is there a way to keep a global variable to the JET resources that maintains the static variable from the C++ code between requests?

Here is snippet of the my C++ code for the PHP extension:

```
void php_saxonc_initialize(void){
   if(SProcessor::jvmCreatedCPP == 0){
    SProcessor::jvmCreatedCPP=1;

    SProcessor::sxn_environ= (sxnc_environment *)malloc(sizeof(sxnc_environment));

    /*
     * First of all, load required component.
     * By the time of JET initialization, all components should be loaded.
     */

    SProcessor::sxn_environ->myDllHandle = loadDefaultDll ();

    /*
     * Initialize JET run-time.
     * The handle of loaded component is used to retrieve Invocation API.
     */
    initDefaultJavaRT (SProcessor::sxn_environ); 
    }
}


PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(saxon)
{


    php_saxonc_initialize();

    zend_class_entry ce;
    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "SProcessor", SProcessor_methods);
    ....
```

Having been reading up on global in PHP extensions it seems to me I have to setup things up using globals. By using ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS:

```
ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS(saxon)
    static sxnc_environment * sxn_environ;
    php_saxonc_initialize();
ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS(saxon)

ZEND_DECLARE_MODULE_GLOBALS(saxon)
```

I don't think this is quite right, but not finding the write documentation.

Comment: For code questions and understanding them, it's a good idea to extract a [mcve]. For Stack Overflow, providing that alongside your question is actually mandatory.

Comment: Yes indeed example would help. I have edited the post. Thanks